# Плавное изменение RGB цвета фона HTML-страницы с помощью JS

Tags: javascript, html

Нужно, что бы на каждое действие таймера, менялся фон страницы в RGB формате.
Я набросал немного, но у меня меняется только один канал и то, как-то не так.

```js
function start() {
  var t = document.getElementById('t1').innerText;
  s = parseInt(t) + 1;
  document.getElementById('t1').innerText = s;
  if (s < 255) {
    document.bgColor = 'RGB(' + s + ',00,00)';
  } else {
    clearInterval(time);
  }
}
var time = window.setInterval('start()', 1000);

function stop() {
  clearInterval(time);
}
```

```html
<body onload='start();'>
  <div id="t1" style="background-color: red;">0</div>
  <input type='button' value='stop' onclick='stop();'>
</body>
```

Comment: Ну так Вы и меняете только один канал (`'RGB(' + s + ',00,00)'`, причем к цвету фона всего документа (`document.bgColor = `)

Comment: 3 канала === 3 массива, по `i, j, k` до 255, вот и ставите `rgb(i, j, k)`, с таймаутом каким вам нужно. Но чтобы плавно сделать вам придется увеличивать логику так же как и должны сработать массивы, до 255 элемента, потом обнулять текущий, прибавлять к следующему 1 и опять до 255

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев   Получается нужно сделать s = parseInt(t) + 1; k = parseInt(t) + 1; n = parseInt(t) + 1;  document.bgColor = 'RGB(' + s + ',' + k + ',' + n + ')';

Comment: Ну если все переменные одинаковые, зачем дублировать? `s = parseInt(t) + 1;document.getElementById('t1').bgColor = 'RGB(' + s + ',' + s + ',' + s + ')';`

Comment: Перебор будет в 255 цветов, т.к. у вас получится `1,1,1` => `2,2,2` => `255,255,255` ... Но в rgb цветов `255*255*255=16581375`. Поэтому нужно добавить логику повышения индекса вышестоящего индекса, если нижестоящий нарастил 255

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев вот с этой логикой я и не могу разобраться

Comment: Кстати цвет у вас доходит до 254, но в rgb он не записывается, т.к. не проходит условие s <= 255, должно быть. Плохо что не можете, т.к. вы уже написали для 1 элемента ваш код, добавьте второй. проверьте, затем 3й и проверьте, логика у вас верная. Попробуйте решить сами эту задачу, она достаточно простая, но нужно включить логику. Программирование дело не простое, но нужен толчок которые я подкинул в комментариях. Главное сделайте поэтапно

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев Вот я пока что и придумать не могу, как сделать так, чтобы после дохождения первого канала до 255 остальные каналы увеличивались. Так же нужно что бы плавно перетекание из одного цвета переходило в другой

Answer (score 1):

Набросал пример как можно это сделать. Разберитесь как именно оно работает, почему цвет меняется именно так, и как вообще устроено rgb, в этом примере показано как меняется индекс.

```js
var colors = [0, 0, 0];
var time = window.setInterval('start()', 1);

function start() {
  if (colors[2] === 255) {
    colors[1]++;
    colors[2] = 0;
  }
  if (colors[1] === 255) {
    colors[0]++;
    colors[1] = 0;
  }
  
  colors[2]++;
  
  document.getElementById('t1').innerText = colors.join(',');
  document.body.bgColor = 'RGB('+colors.join(',')+')';
  
  if (colors[0] === 255) {
    clearInterval(time);
  }
}

function stop() {
  clearInterval(time);
}
```

```html
<body onload='start();'>
  <div id="t1" style="background-color: red;">0</div>
  <input type='button' value='stop' onclick='stop();'>
</body>
```

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас разберусь.